# Cannot connect to service on NodePort using Kubernetes on Windows Docker Desktop

Tags: docker, kubernetes, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-5, docker-desktop

Firstly, this is my folder:

[image]

This is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0 AS build-env
WORKDIR /app

COPY *.csproj ./
RUN dotnet restore

COPY . ./
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-env /app/out .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "PlatformService.dll"]
```

platforms-depl.yaml (deployment file)

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: platforms-depl
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: platformservice
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: platformservice
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: platformservice
          image: hao14102000/platformservice:latest
```

platforms-np-srv.yaml (NodePort Service file)

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: platformnpservice-srv
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: platformservice
  ports:
    - name: platformservice
      protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 80
```

When I apply 2 files this is what I see:

[image]

When I try to connect on port `31023` using both options below:

```
http://localhost:31023/api/platforms
http://10.109.215.230:31023/api/platforms
```

It doesn't work. This happens:

[image]

[image]

I don't know what wrong with this...

Comment: check  that your  endpoints   are  ok？

Comment: Where and how is kubernetes cluster deployed? Localhost may not be working in some instances

Comment: @MiffaYoung my endpoint works well, run in localhost, and in docker env it works well, only with k8s env it not work ...

Comment: @moonkotte I deploy kubernetes in docker desktop in my laptop...data is use in memory, I test in local env and docker env success

Comment: I think 1 in two YAML files miss some config ...but I don't know what...and in the picture,... It's give me a port but when I use this port... it fails to connect...

Comment: Sorry for my reply so late... I just finished my class at 5h30 in VietNam...Sorry about my late reply...

Comment: You don't need to apologise, when you can reply you reply and it's fine :) I have a suspicious that it's related to kubernetes realization using `docker desktop`. Please try [port-forwarding](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/port-forward-access-application-cluster/) to expose service on your host directly. Command will be `kubectl port-forward service/platformnpservice-srv 8080:80 &` and then access the app on `localhost:8080`

Comment: @moonkotte thanks I will try it,...

Comment: @moonkotte thanks, It's work..., thanks for your help...

Comment: @Hao Cool, now I'll install `docker desktop` on my windows machine and come back with answer what else you can do. `port-forward` is a working solution, but I'd say kind of workaround.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### What happens with Linux containers:

Kubernetes on Windows Docker Desktop by default runs its components in WSL2 (Windows subsystem for Linux), it's separate virtual machine with its own IP address and `localhost`. This is the reason why service is not reachable on `localhost` from host OS (in this case Windows).

Another option is to disable `using WSL2 based engine` in settings, instead `hyper-v` will be used and virtual machine will be created however in Docker Desktop it's said that preferably WSL2 should be used for performance benefits.

### Available options how to access the service using WSL2:

1. Fastest and easiest (loadbalancer)

Set up a `service` with `LoadBalancer` type. `EXTERNAL-IP` will be localhost which solves all questions immediately. For example:

```
kubectl get svc
NAME         TYPE           CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE
kubernetes   ClusterIP      10.96.0.1      <none>        443/TCP          11m
nginx        LoadBalancer   10.110.15.53   localhost     8080:30654/TCP   4m10s
```

Nginx is available in browser on `localhost:8080`.

2. Using virtual machine's IP and nodeport

Another option is to find `WSL` virtual machine and then access service on this IP and `nodeport`.

To find WSL VM address, you need to run `wsl` command to connect to this VM and then find its IP address:

```
wsl

# ip a | grep eth0

6: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    inet 172.19.xxx.yyy/20 brd 172.19.xxx.yyy scope global eth0
```

Nginx is available in browser on `172.19.xxx.yyy:30654`.

3. Port-forward - for testing purposes

`Port-forward` is useful for testing purposes, but it shouldn't be used on production systems.

To start the proxy to the service, run following command:

```
kubectl port-forward service/nginx 8080:80 &
```

Nginx is available in browser on `localhost:8080`

### Assumptions when Hyper-V is used

First `hyper-v` should be installed on host machine. Note that not all versions of Windows are supported. Please refer to documentation on which versions and how to enable `hyper-v` [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/quick-start/enable-hyper-v).

When `using WSL2 based engine` is deselected, `hyper-v` is used to work with containers. It creates a separate virtual machine which can be found in `Hyper-v Manager`.

- `nodeport` works on localhost + nodeport
- `loadbalancer` doesn't work, you can't connect to `localhost` with service port even though `External-IP` shows `localhost`.

### Windows containers on Windows Docker Desktop

It's also possible to run Windows containers on Windows Docker Desktop.

It's required to change daemon which will be used. In tray select on `switch to Windows containers`. [Switch between linux and windows containers](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/windows/#switch-between-windows-and-linux-containers).

However `kubernetes` option will become unavailable, because `control plane` components are designed to be run on `linux` host.

### Environment:

**OS**: Windows 10 Enterprise, build: 19041.1165

**Docker Desktop**: 4.0.0 (67817)

**Engine**: 20.10.8

**Kubernetes**: 1.21.4

### Useful links:

- [Service types in Kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#publishing-services-service-types)
- [Kubernetes port-forwarding](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/port-forward-access-application-cluster/)
- [Hyper-V](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/about/)
- [Docker Desktop for Windows users](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/windows/#switch-between-windows-and-linux-containers)