# Ingress not forwarding the requests - Docker desktop for Windows and kubernetes

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, nginx-ingress, docker-desktop

**EDIT:**

I deleted minikube, enabled kubernetes in Docker desktop for Windows and installed `ingress-nginx` manually.

```
$helm upgrade --install ingress-nginx ingress-nginx --repo https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx --namespace ingress-nginx --create-namespace
Release "ingress-nginx" does not exist. Installing it now.
Error: rendered manifests contain a resource that already exists. Unable to continue with install: ServiceAccount "ingress-nginx" in namespace "ingress-nginx" exists and cannot be imported into the current release: invalid ownership metadata; annotation validation error: missing key "meta.helm.sh/release-name": must be set to "ingress-nginx"; annotation validation error: missing key "meta.helm.sh/release-namespace": must be set to "ingress-nginx"
```

It gave me an error but I think it's because I did it already before because:

```
$kubectl get svc -n ingress-nginx
NAME                                 TYPE           CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                      AGE
ingress-nginx-controller             LoadBalancer   10.106.222.233   localhost     80:30199/TCP,443:31093/TCP   11m
ingress-nginx-controller-admission   ClusterIP      10.106.52.106    <none>        443/TCP                      11m
```

Then applied all my yaml files again but this time ingress is not getting any address:

```
$kubectl get ing
NAME                CLASS    HOSTS       ADDRESS   PORTS   AGE
myapp-ingress       <none>   myapp.com             80      10m
```

---

I am using docker desktop (windows) and installed nginx-ingress controller via minikube addons enable command:

```
$kubectl get pods -n ingress-nginx
NAME                                        READY   STATUS      RESTARTS   AGE
ingress-nginx-admission-create--1-lp4md     0/1     Completed   0          67m
ingress-nginx-admission-patch--1-jdkn7      0/1     Completed   1          67m
ingress-nginx-controller-5f66978484-6mpfh   1/1     Running     0          67m
```

And applied all my yaml files:

```
$kubectl get svc --all-namespaces -o wide
NAMESPACE       NAME                                 TYPE           CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                      AGE   SELECTOR
default         event-service-svc                    ClusterIP      10.108.251.79    <none>        80/TCP                       16m   app=event-service-app
default         kubernetes                           ClusterIP      10.96.0.1        <none>        443/TCP                      16m   <none>
default         mssql-clusterip-srv                  ClusterIP      10.98.10.22      <none>        1433/TCP                     16m   app=mssql
default         mssql-loadbalancer                   LoadBalancer   10.109.106.174   <pending>     1433:31430/TCP               16m   app=mssql
default         user-service-svc                     ClusterIP      10.111.128.73    <none>        80/TCP                       16m   app=user-service-app
ingress-nginx   ingress-nginx-controller             NodePort       10.101.112.245   <none>        80:31583/TCP,443:30735/TCP   68m   app.kubernetes.io/component=controller,app.kubernetes.io/instance=ingress-nginx,app.kubernetes.io/name=ingress-nginx
ingress-nginx   ingress-nginx-controller-admission   ClusterIP      10.105.169.167   <none>        443/TCP                      68m   app.kubernetes.io/component=controller,app.kubernetes.io/instance=ingress-nginx,app.kubernetes.io/name=ingress-nginx
kube-system     kube-dns                             ClusterIP      10.96.0.10       <none>        53/UDP,53/TCP,9153/TCP       72m   k8s-app=kube-dns
```

All pods and services seems to be running properly. Checked the pod logs, all migrations etc. has worked and app is up and running. But when I try to send an HTTP request, I get a socket hang up error. I've checked all the logs for all pods, couldn't find anything useful.

```
$kubectl get ingress
NAME                CLASS   HOSTS           ADDRESS     PORTS   AGE
myapp-ingress   nginx   myapp.com       localhost   80      74s
```

This one is also a bit weird, I was expecting ADRESS to be set to an IP not to localhost. So adding 127.0.0.1 entry for myapp.com in /etc/hosts also didn't seem so right.

My question here is what I might be doing wrong? Or how can I even trace where are my requests are being forwarded to?

ingress-svc.yaml

```
  apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
    kind: Ingress
    metadata:
      name: myapp-ingress
    spec:
      rules:
      - host: myapp.com
        http:
          paths:
          - path: /api/Users
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: user-service-svc
                port:
                  number: 80
          - path: /api/Events
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: event-service-svc
                port:
                  number: 80
```

events-depl.yaml:

```
  apiVersion: apps/v1
    kind: Deployment
    metadata:
      name: event-service-app
      labels:
        app: event-service-app
    spec:
      replicas: 1
      selector:
        matchLabels:
          app: event-service-app
      template:
        metadata:
          labels:
            app: event-service-app
        spec:
          containers:
            - name: event-service-app
              image: ghcr.io/myapp/event-service:master
              imagePullPolicy: Always
              ports:
                - containerPort: 80
          imagePullSecrets:
            - name: myapp
    ---
    apiVersion: v1
    kind: Service
    metadata:
      name: event-service-svc
    spec:
      selector:
        app: event-service-app
      ports:
        - protocol: TCP
          port: 80
          targetPort: 80
```

Comment: Which minikube driver is used? Can be checked in `.minikube/profiles/minikube/config.json`. When by default it used `docker` driver, I didn't have `localhost` in ADDRESS for ingress. This happens on docker desktop when kubernetes is enabled. How exactly are you trying to reach your service via ingress?

Comment: @moonkotte Minikube driver is docker. I've tried disabling kubernetes in docker desktop and recreate everything but again it gives localhost for ingress address. I am trying to reach a service via postman using both localhost or myapp.com but gives me socket hang up error.

Comment: Which `minikube version` is used? Also what happens if you try to reach your address using `myapp.com:31583`? This is a node port of ingress-nginx-controller service

Comment: @moonkotte minikube version: v1.24.0. When I try it with 31583 it throws an connection refused error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Reproduction

I reproduced the case using minikube `v1.24.0`, Docker desktop `4.2.0`, engine `20.10.10`

First, `localhost` in ingress appears due to logic, it doesn't really matter what IP address is behind the domain in `/etc/hosts`, I added a different one for testing and still it showed localhost. Only `metallb` will provide an IP address from set up network.

### What happens

When minikube driver is `docker`, minikube creates a big container (VM) where kubernetes components are run. This can be checked by running `docker ps` command in host system:

```
$ docker ps

CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                                 COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS          PORTS                                                                                                                                  NAMES
f087dc669944   gcr.io/k8s-minikube/kicbase:v0.0.28   "/usr/local/bin/entr…"   16 minutes ago   Up 16 minutes   127.0.0.1:59762->22/tcp, 127.0.0.1:59758->2376/tcp, 127.0.0.1:59760->5000/tcp, 127.0.0.1:59761->8443/tcp, 127.0.0.1:59759->32443/tcp   minikube
```

And then `minikube ssh` to get inside this container and run `docker ps` to see all kubernetes containers.

Moving forward. Before introducing `ingress`, it's already clear that even `NodePort` doesn't work as intended. Let's check it.

There are two ways to get `minikube VM IP`:

1. run `minikube IP`
2. `kubectl get nodes -o wide` and find the node's IP

What should happen next with `NodePort` is requests should go to `minikube_IP:Nodeport` while it doesn't work. It happens because docker containers inside the minikube VM are not exposed outside of the cluster which is another docker container.

On `minikube` to access services within cluster there is a special command - [`minikube service %service_name%`](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/commands/service/) which will create a direct tunnel to the service inside the `minikube VM` (you can see that it contains `service URL` with `NodePort` which is supposed to be working):

```
$ minikube service echo

|-----------|------|-------------|---------------------------|
| NAMESPACE | NAME | TARGET PORT |            URL            |
|-----------|------|-------------|---------------------------|
| default   | echo |        8080 | http://192.168.49.2:32034 |
|-----------|------|-------------|---------------------------|
* Starting tunnel for service echo.
|-----------|------|-------------|------------------------|
| NAMESPACE | NAME | TARGET PORT |          URL           |
|-----------|------|-------------|------------------------|
| default   | echo |             | http://127.0.0.1:61991 |
|-----------|------|-------------|------------------------|
* Opening service default/echo in default browser...
! Because you are using a Docker driver on windows, the terminal needs to be open to run it
```

And now it's available on host machine:

```
$ curl http://127.0.0.1:61991/

StatusCode        : 200
StatusDescription : OK
```

### Adding ingress

Moving forward and adding ingress.

```
$ minikube addons enable ingress
$ kubectl get svc -A

NAMESPACE       NAME                                 TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                      AGE
default         echo                                 NodePort    10.111.57.237   <none>        8080:32034/TCP               25m
ingress-nginx   ingress-nginx-controller             NodePort    10.104.52.175   <none>        80:31041/TCP,443:31275/TCP   2m12s
```

Trying to get any response from `ingress` by hitting `minikube_IP:NodePort` with no luck:

```
$ curl 192.168.49.2:31041

curl : Unable to connect to the remote server
At line:1 char:1
+ curl 192.168.49.2:31041
```

Trying to create a tunnel with `minikube service` command:

```
$ minikube service ingress-nginx-controller -n ingress-nginx

|---------------|--------------------------|-------------|---------------------------|
|   NAMESPACE   |           NAME           | TARGET PORT |            URL            |
|---------------|--------------------------|-------------|---------------------------|
| ingress-nginx | ingress-nginx-controller | http/80     | http://192.168.49.2:31041 |
|               |                          | https/443   | http://192.168.49.2:31275 |
|---------------|--------------------------|-------------|---------------------------|
* Starting tunnel for service ingress-nginx-controller.
|---------------|--------------------------|-------------|------------------------|
|   NAMESPACE   |           NAME           | TARGET PORT |          URL           |
|---------------|--------------------------|-------------|------------------------|
| ingress-nginx | ingress-nginx-controller |             | http://127.0.0.1:62234 |
|               |                          |             | http://127.0.0.1:62235 |
|---------------|--------------------------|-------------|------------------------|
* Opening service ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx-controller in default browser...
* Opening service ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx-controller in default browser...
! Because you are using a Docker driver on windows, the terminal needs to be open to run it.
```

And getting `404` from `ingress-nginx` which means we can send requests to ingress:

```
$ curl http://127.0.0.1:62234

curl : 404 Not Found
nginx
At line:1 char:1
+ curl http://127.0.0.1:62234
```

### Solutions

Above I explained what happens. Here are three solutions how to get it work:

1. Use another [minikube driver](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/drivers/) (e.g. virtualbox. I used `hyperv` since my laptop has windows 10 pro)

`minikube ip` will return "normal" IP address of virtual machine and all network functionality will work just fine. You will need to add this IP address into `/etc/hosts` for domain used in ingress rule

**Note!** Even though `localhost` was shown in `kubectl get ing ingress` output in `ADDRESS`.

2. Use built-in kubernetes feature in Docker desktop for Windows.

You will need to [manually install `ingress-nginx`](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/#bare-metal-clusters) and change `ingress-nginx-controller` service type from `NodePort` to `LoadBalancer` so it will be available on `localhost` and will be working. Please find [my another answer about Docker desktop for Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69113528/15537201)

3. (testing only) - use port-forward

It's almost exactly the same idea as `minikube service` command. But with more control. You will open a tunnel from host VM port `80` to `ingress-nginx-controller` service (eventually pod) on port `80` as well. `/etc/hosts` should contain `127.0.0.1 test.domain` entity.

```
$ kubectl port-forward service/ingress-nginx-controller -n ingress-nginx 80:80

Forwarding from 127.0.0.1:80 -> 80
Forwarding from [::1]:80 -> 80
```

And testing it works:

```
$ curl test.domain

StatusCode        : 200
StatusDescription : OK
```

### Update for kubernetes in docker desktop on windows and ingress:

On modern `ingress-nginx` versions `.spec.ingressClassName` should be added to ingress rules. See [last updates](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/#i-have-only-one-instance-of-the-ingresss-nginx-controller-in-my-cluster-what-should-i-do), so ingress rule should look like:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
...
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx # can be checked by kubectl get ingressclass
  rules:
  - host: myapp.com
    http:
      ...
```

Comment: Please see my edited question.

Comment: @osumatu What exactly did you do? How did you start `minikube` after you deleted it? Also `ingress-nginx-controller` service has `EXTERNAL-IP` localhost, have you tried hitting localhost now?

Comment: I deleted minikube, enabled K8S in docker desktop, installed ingress-nginx manually. (Removed all the resources and successfully installed). When I try to hit localhost now, nginx returns 404.

Comment: @osumatu Okay, added a part to my answer. Appeared this is crucial for kubernetes in docker desktop and ingress-nginx. Once it added, IP address will be shown in `kubectl get ing` as well (after about 1 min) + your application should be listening on `/api/Users/`. If it listens to `/`, then [rewrite annotation](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#rewrite) should be added like `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /`

Comment: Once I've added the ingressClassName finally my svc got an address! But this time I am getting 502 error for the endpoints.

Comment: Ah sorry that was due to wrong port number, now everything works perfectly! Thanks man, I really appreciate it.

Comment: @osumatu You're very welcome!

Comment: Big Thanks Man. I tired and lost hope but just `kubectl port-forward service/ingress-nginx-controller -n ingress-nginx 80:80` worked for me and I needed that to show demo. Big THanks man.