# Problem with deploying blazor server app to Kubernetes

Tags: c#, docker, kubernetes, blazor

### **Edited with new data after complete Kubernetes wipe-out.**

Lately I am trying to do a test deploy of a Blazor server app on locally hosted Kubernetes instance running on docker desktop.

I managed to correctly spin up the app in a container, migrations were applied etc, logs are telling me that the app is running and waiting.

**Steps taken after resetting Kubernetes using `Reset Kubernetes Kluster` in Docker Desktop:**

- Modified `hosts` file to include `127.0.0.1 scp.com`
- Added secret containing key to mssql
- Installed Ngnix controller using `kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/controller-v1.1.0/deploy/static/provider/cloud/deploy.yaml`
- Applied local volume claim - `local-pvc.yaml`

  ```yaml
  apiVersion: v1
  kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
  metadata:
      name: mssql-claim
  spec:
      accessModes:
          - ReadWriteMany
      resources:
          requests:
              storage: 250Mi
  ```
- Applied mssql instance and cluster ip - `mssql-scanapp-depl.yaml`

  ```yaml
  apiVersion: apps/v1
  kind: Deployment
  metadata:
      name: mssql-depl
  spec:
      replicas: 1
      selector:
          matchLabels:
              app: mssql
      template:
          metadata:
              labels:
                  app: mssql
          spec:
              containers:
                  - name: mssql
                    image: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest
                    ports:
                        - containerPort: 1433
                    env:
                        - name: MSSQL_PID
                          value: "Express"
                        - name: ACCEPT_EULA
                          value: "Y"
                        - name: SA_PASSWORD
                          valueFrom:
                              secretKeyRef:
                                  name: mssql
                                  key: SA_PASSWORD
                    volumeMounts:
                        - mountPath: /var/opt/mssql/data
                          name: mssqldb
              volumes:
                  - name: mssqldb
                    persistentVolumeClaim:
                        claimName: mssql-claim
  ---
  apiVersion: v1
  kind: Service
  metadata:
      name: mssql-clusterip-srv
  spec:
      type: ClusterIP
      selector:
          app: mssql
      ports:
          - name: mssql
            protocol: TCP
            port: 1433
            targetPort: 1433
  ---
  apiVersion: v1
  kind: Service
  metadata:
      name: mssql-loadbalancer
  spec:
      type: LoadBalancer
      selector:
          app: mssql
      ports:        
          - protocol: TCP
            port: 1433
            targetPort: 1433
  ```
- Applied Blazor application and cluster ip - `scanapp-depl.yaml`:

  ```yaml
  apiVersion: apps/v1
  kind: Deployment
  metadata:
      name: scanapp-depl
  spec:
      replicas: 1
      selector:
          matchLabels:
              app: scanapp
      template:
          metadata:
              labels:
                  app: scanapp
          spec:
              containers:
                  - name: scanapp
                    image: scanapp:1.0
  ---
  apiVersion: v1
  kind: Service
  metadata:
      name: scanapp-clusterip-srv
  spec:
      type: ClusterIP
      selector:
          app: scanapp
      ports:
          - name: ui
            protocol: TCP
            port: 8080
            targetPort: 80
          - name: ui2
            protocol: TCP
            port: 8081
            targetPort: 443
          - name: scanapp0
            protocol: TCP
            port: 5000
            targetPort: 5000
          - name: scanapp1
            protocol: TCP
            port: 5001
            targetPort: 5001
          - name: scanapp5
            protocol: TCP
            port: 5005
            targetPort: 5005
  ```
- Applied Ingress - `ingress-srv.yaml`:

  ```yaml
  apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
  kind: Ingress
  metadata:
    name: ingress-srv
    annotations:
      nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /    
      nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/affinity: "cookie"
      nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-name: "affinity"
      nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-expires: "14400"
      nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-max-age: "14400"
  spec:
    ingressClassName: nginx
    rules:
        - host: scp.com
          http:
              paths:
              - path: /
                pathType: Prefix
                backend:
                  service:
                    name: scanapp-clusterip-srv
                    port:
                      number: 8080
  ```

After all of this, Blazor app starts good, connects to mssql instance, seeds database and awaits for clients. Logs are as follows:

> [15:18:53 INF] Starting up...
> [15:18:53 WRN] Storing keys in a directory '/root/.aspnet
> /DataProtection-Keys' that may not be persisted outside of the container. Protected data will be unavailable when container is destroyed.
> [15:18:55 INF] AuthorizationPolicy Configuration started ...
> [15:18:55 INF] Policy 'LocationMustBeSady' was configured \successfully.
> [15:18:55 INF] AuthorizationPolicy Configuration completed.
> [15:18:55 INF] Now listening on: http://[::]:80
> [15:18:55 INF] Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
> [15:18:55 INF] Hosting environment: docker
> [15:18:55 INF] Content root path: /app

## **As stated in the beginning - I cannot, for the love of all, get into my blazor app from browser - I tried:**

- scp.com
- scp.com:8080
- scp.com:5000
- scp.com:5001
- scp.com:5005

**Also, `kubectl get ingress` now does not display ADDRESS value  like before and `kubectl get services` now says *pending* for `mssql-loadbalancer` and `ingress-nginx-controller` EXTERNAL-IP - detailed logs at the end of this post**

Nothing seems to work, so there must be something wrong with my config files and I have no idea what could it be.
Also, note that there is no `NodePort` configured this time.

In addition, Dockerfile for Blazor app:

```yaml
    # https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-dotnet
    FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0 AS build
    WORKDIR /source
    EXPOSE 5000
    EXPOSE 5001
    EXPOSE 5005
    EXPOSE 80
    EXPOSE 443
    
    LABEL name="ScanApp"
    
    # copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
    COPY ScanApp/*.csproj ScanApp/
    COPY ScanApp.Application/*.csproj ScanApp.Application/
    COPY ScanApp.Common/*.csproj ScanApp.Common/
    COPY ScanApp.Domain/*.csproj ScanApp.Domain/
    COPY ScanApp.Infrastructure/*.csproj ScanApp.Infrastructure/
    COPY ScanApp.Tests/*.csproj ScanApp.Tests/
    
    Run ln -sf /usr/share/zoneinfo/posix/Europe/Warsaw /etc/localtime
    RUN dotnet restore ScanApp/ScanApp.csproj
    
    # copy and build app and libraries
    COPY ScanApp/ ScanApp/
    COPY ScanApp.Application/ ScanApp.Application/
    COPY ScanApp.Common/ ScanApp.Common/
    COPY ScanApp.Domain/ ScanApp.Domain/
    COPY ScanApp.Infrastructure/ ScanApp.Infrastructure/
    COPY ScanApp.Tests/ ScanApp.Tests/
    WORKDIR /source/ScanApp
    RUN dotnet build -c release --no-restore
    
    # test stage -- exposes optional entrypoint
    # target entrypoint with: docker build --target test
    FROM build AS test
    WORKDIR /source/ScanApp.Tests
    COPY tests/ .
    ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "test", "--logger:trx"]
    
    FROM build AS publish
    RUN dotnet publish -c release --no-build -o /app
    
    # final stage/image
    FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0
    WORKDIR /app
    COPY --from=publish /app .
    ENV ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT="docker"
    ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "ScanApp.dll"]
```

### **kubectl outputs**

`kubectl get ingress` output:

| NAME | CLASS | HOSTS | ADDRESS | PORTS | AGE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ingress-srv | nginx | scp.com |  | 80 | 35m |

`kubectl get pods --all-namespaces` output:

| **NAME** | **READY** | **STATUS** | **RESTARTS** | **AGE** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| default | mssql-depl-7f46b5c696-7hhbr | 1/1 | Running | 0 |
| default | scanapp-depl-76f56bc6df-4jcq4 | 1/1 | Running | 0 |
| ingress-nginx | ingress-nginx-admission-create-qdnck | 0/1 | Completed | 0 |
| ingress-nginx | ingress-nginx-admission-patch-chxqn | 0/1 | Completed | 1 |
| ingress-nginx | ingress-nginx-controller-54bfb9bb-f6gsf | 1/1 | Running | 0 |
| kube-system | coredns-558bd4d5db-mr8p7 | 1/1 | Running | 0 |
| kube-system | coredns-558bd4d5db-rdw2d | 1/1 | Running | 0 |
| kube-system | etcd-docker-desktop | 1/1 | Running | 0 |
| kube-system | kube-apiserver-docker-desktop | 1/1 | Running | 0 |
| kube-system | kube-controller-manager-docker-desktop | 1/1 | Running | 0 |
| kube-system | kube-proxy-pws8f | 1/1 | Running | 0 |
| kube-system | kube-scheduler-docker-desktop | 1/1 | Running | 0 |
| kube-system | storage-provisioner | 1/1 | Running | 0 |
| kube-system | vpnkit-controller | 1/1 | Running | 6 |

`kubectl get deployments --all-namespaces` output

| **NAME** | **READY** | **UP-TO-DATE** | **AVAILABLE** | **AGE** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| default | mssql-depl | 1/1 | 1 | 1 |
| default | scanapp-depl | 1/1 | 1 | 1 |
| ingress-nginx | ingress-nginx-controller | 1/1 | 1 | 1 |
| kube-system | coredns | 2/2 | 2 | 2 |

`kubectl get services --all-namespaces` output:

| **NAME** | **TYPE** | **CLUSTER-IP** | **EXTERNAL-IP** | **PORT(S)** | **AGE** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| default | kubernetes | ClusterIP | 10.96.0.1 | none | 443/TCP |
| default | mssql-clusterip-srv | ClusterIP | 10.97.96.94 | none | 1433/TCP |
| default | mssql-loadbalancer | LoadBalancer | 10.107.235.49 | pending | 1433:30149/TCP |
| default | scanapp-clusterip-srv | ClusterIP | 10.109.116.183 | none | 8080/TCP,8081/TCP,5000/TCP,5001/TCP,5005/TCP |
| ingress-nginx | ingress-nginx-controller | LoadBalancer | 10.103.89.226 | pending | 80:30562/TCP,443:31733/TCP |
| ingress-nginx | ingress-nginx-controller-admission | ClusterIP | 10.111.235.243 | none | 443/TCP |
| kube-system | kube-dns | ClusterIP | 10.96.0.10 | none | 53/UDP,53/TCP,9153/TCP |

### Ingress logs:

> ---
>
> NGINX Ingress controller
>
> Release:       v1.1.0
>
> Build:         cacbee86b6ccc45bde8ffc184521bed3022e7dee
>
> Repository:    https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx
>
> nginx version: nginx/1.19.9
>
> ---
>
> W1129 15:00:51.705331       8 client_config.go:615] Neither
> --kubeconfig nor --master was specified.  Using the inClusterConfig.  This might not work.
>
> I1129 15:00:51.705452       8 main.go:223] "Creating API client"
> host="https://10.96.0.1:443"
>
> I1129 15:00:51.721575       8 main.go:267] "Running in Kubernetes
> cluster" major="1" minor="21" git="v1.21.5" state="clean"
> commit="aea7bbadd2fc0cd689de94a54e5b7b758869d691"
> platform="linux/amd64"
>
> I1129 15:00:51.872964       8 main.go:104] "SSL fake certificate
> created"
> file="/etc/ingress-controller/ssl/default-fake-certificate.pem"
>
> I1129 15:00:51.890273       8 ssl.go:531] "loading tls certificate"
> path="/usr/local/certificates/cert" key="/usr/local/certificates/key"
>
> I1129 15:00:51.910104       8 nginx.go:255] "Starting NGINX Ingress
> controller"
>
> I1129 15:00:51.920821       8 event.go:282]
> Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"ConfigMap", Namespace:"ingress-nginx",
> Name:"ingress-nginx-controller",
> UID:"51060a85-d3a0-40de-b549-cf59e8fa7b08", APIVersion:"v1",
> ResourceVersion:"733", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Normal' reason: 'CREATE'
> ConfigMap ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx-controller
>
> I1129 15:00:53.112043       8 nginx.go:297] "Starting NGINX process"
>
> I1129 15:00:53.112213       8 leaderelection.go:248] attempting to
> acquire leader lease ingress-nginx/ingress-controller-leader...
>
> I1129 15:00:53.112275       8 nginx.go:317] "Starting validation
> webhook" address=":8443" certPath="/usr/local/certificates/cert"
> keyPath="/usr/local/certificates/key"
>
> I1129 15:00:53.112468       8 controller.go:155] "Configuration
> changes detected, backend reload required"
>
> I1129 15:00:53.118295       8 leaderelection.go:258] successfully
> acquired lease ingress-nginx/ingress-controller-leader
>
> I1129 15:00:53.119467       8 status.go:84] "New leader elected"
> identity="ingress-nginx-controller-54bfb9bb-f6gsf"
>
> I1129 15:00:53.141609       8 controller.go:172] "Backend successfully
> reloaded"
>
> I1129 15:00:53.141804       8 controller.go:183] "Initial sync,
> sleeping for 1 second"
>
> I1129 15:00:53.141908       8 event.go:282]
> Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"Pod", Namespace:"ingress-nginx",
> Name:"ingress-nginx-controller-54bfb9bb-f6gsf",
> UID:"54e0c0c6-40ea-439e-b1a2-7787f1b37e7a", APIVersion:"v1",
> ResourceVersion:"766", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Normal' reason: 'RELOAD'
> NGINX reload triggered due to a change in configuration
>
> I1129 15:04:25.107359       8 admission.go:149] processed ingress via
> admission controller {testedIngressLength:1 testedIngressTime:0.022s
> renderingIngressLength:1 renderingIngressTime:0s admissionTime:17.9kBs
> testedConfigurationSize:0.022}
>
> I1129 15:04:25.107395       8 main.go:101] "successfully validated
> configuration, accepting" ingress="ingress-srv/default"
>
> I1129 15:04:25.110109       8 store.go:424] "Found valid IngressClass"
> ingress="default/ingress-srv" ingressclass="nginx"
>
> I1129 15:04:25.110698       8 controller.go:155] "Configuration
> changes detected, backend reload required"
>
> I1129 15:04:25.111057       8 event.go:282]
> Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"Ingress", Namespace:"default",
> Name:"ingress-srv", UID:"6c15d014-ac14-404e-8b5e-d8526736c52a",
> APIVersion:"networking.k8s.io/v1", ResourceVersion:"1198",
> FieldPath:""}): type: 'Normal' reason: 'Sync' Scheduled for sync
>
> I1129 15:04:25.143417       8 controller.go:172] "Backend successfully
> reloaded"
>
> I1129 15:04:25.143767       8 event.go:282]
> Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"Pod", Namespace:"ingress-nginx",
> Name:"ingress-nginx-controller-54bfb9bb-f6gsf",
> UID:"54e0c0c6-40ea-439e-b1a2-7787f1b37e7a", APIVersion:"v1",
> ResourceVersion:"766", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Normal' reason: 'RELOAD'
> NGINX reload triggered due to a change in configuration
>
> I1129 15:06:11.447313       8 admission.go:149] processed ingress via
> admission controller {testedIngressLength:1 testedIngressTime:0.02s
> renderingIngressLength:1 renderingIngressTime:0s admissionTime:17.9kBs
> testedConfigurationSize:0.02}
>
> I1129 15:06:11.447349       8 main.go:101] "successfully validated
> configuration, accepting" ingress="ingress-srv/default"
>
> I1129 15:06:11.449266       8 event.go:282]
> Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"Ingress", Namespace:"default",
> Name:"ingress-srv", UID:"6c15d014-ac14-404e-8b5e-d8526736c52a",
> APIVersion:"networking.k8s.io/v1", ResourceVersion:"1347",
> FieldPath:""}): type: 'Normal' reason: 'Sync' Scheduled for sync
>
> I1129 15:06:11.449669       8 controller.go:155] "Configuration
> changes detected, backend reload required"
>
> I1129 15:06:11.499772       8 controller.go:172] "Backend successfully
> reloaded"
>
> I1129 15:06:11.500210       8 event.go:282]
> Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"Pod", Namespace:"ingress-nginx",
> Name:"ingress-nginx-controller-54bfb9bb-f6gsf",
> UID:"54e0c0c6-40ea-439e-b1a2-7787f1b37e7a", APIVersion:"v1",
> ResourceVersion:"766", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Normal' reason: 'RELOAD'
> NGINX reload triggered due to a change in configuration

Comment: First as it was mentioned in answer, you don't need to use `nodePort` if service is behind `ingress`. Even if you do, you don't need to specify the `nodePort` number - it will be assigned automatically. Then. Not sure why it started working on `scp.com:30080` while `ingress` is listening on `localhost`. Recently I got similar question, try adding `ingressClassName: nginx` in `ingress.yaml` spec - see the bottom part of [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70011639/ingress-not-forwarding-the-requests-docker-desktop-for-windows-and-kubernetes/70025145#70025145)

Comment: I have edited my original post heavily with new data and un-marked my answer, because after resetting kubernetes problem returned. Maybe You could take a look at this again?

Answer (score 2):

### **AFTER COMPLETE RESET OF KUBERNETES THIS SOLUTION DOES NOT WORK!**

**Will re-edit main question

Leaving post for future use**

I solved the problem, or at least I think so.
In addition to [@moonkotte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70115934/problem-with-deploying-blazor-server-app-to-kubernetes?noredirect=1#comment123954982_70115934) suggestion to add the `ingressClassName: nginx` to `ingress-srv.yaml` I also changed the ingress port configuration so that it points to port `80` now.

Thanks to those changes using `scp.com` now correctly opens my app.
Also, using NodePort access I can visit my app using `localhost:30080`, where the 30080 port was set automatically (I removed the `nodePort` configuration line from `scanapp-np-srv.yaml`)

Why does the port in `ingress-srv.yaml` have to be set to 80 if `clusterIp` configuration states to set port `8080` to target port `80` - I don't know, I do not fully understand the inner workings of Kubernetes configuration - **All explanations are more than welcome.**

Current state of main configuration files:

`ingress-srv.yaml`:

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-srv
  annotations:  
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/affinity: "cookie"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-name: "affinity"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-expires: "14400"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-max-age: "14400"
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
      - host: scp.com
        http:
            paths:
            - path: /
              pathType: Prefix
              backend:
                service:
                  name: scanapp-clusterip-srv
                  port:
                    number: 80
```

`scanapp-np-srv.yaml`:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
    name: scanappnpservice-srv
spec:
    type: NodePort
    selector:
        app: scanapp
    ports:    
        - name: ui
          port: 8080
          targetPort: 80
        - name: scanapp0
          protocol: TCP
          port: 5000
          targetPort: 5000
        - name: scanapp1
          protocol: TCP
          port: 5001
          targetPort: 5001
        - name: scanapp5
          protocol: TCP
          port: 5005
          targetPort: 5005
```

`scanapp-depl.yaml`:

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
    name: scanapp-depl
spec:
    replicas: 1
    selector:
        matchLabels:
            app: scanapp
    template:
        metadata:
            labels:
                app: scanapp
        spec:
            containers:
                - name: scanapp
                  image: scanapp:1.0
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
    name: scanapp-clusterip-srv
spec:
    type: ClusterIP
    selector:
        app: scanapp
    ports:
        - name: ui
          protocol: TCP
          port: 8080
          targetPort: 80
        - name: ui2
          protocol: TCP
          port: 8081
          targetPort: 443
        - name: scanapp0
          protocol: TCP
          port: 5000
          targetPort: 5000
        - name: scanapp1
          protocol: TCP
          port: 5001
          targetPort: 5001
        - name: scanapp5
          protocol: TCP
          port: 5005
          targetPort: 5005
```

Rest of files remained untouched.

Comment: When you access your app on NodePort, you don't use ingress at all. So it's not a real option if you need to expose the service in real life. As of port 80 - you should check everything, recreate from scratch with simple `nginx` deploy and find the inconsistency - ingress routes requests on service's clusterIP.

Answer (score 0):

First, you don't need a `NodePort` service, just a `ClusterIP`. Nodeports are used if you want to access the service directly without going through the ingress controller.

In case you want to test this with a `NodePort`, you will need to define one, eg

```yaml
- name: ui
  port: 8080
  targetPort: 80
  nodePort: 38080  # needs to be higher than 30000
```

But looking at your ingress rule it seems a bit off. I would try the following:

```yaml
spec:
  rules:
    - host: scp.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            backend:
              serviceName: scanapp-clusterip-srv
              servicePort: ui
```

Comment: 1: Needed to change port number to 30080 - maximum is 32767. 
2: Unfortunately Your second advice ends with validation error: `[ValidationError(Ingress.spec.rules[0].http.paths[0].backend): unknown field serviceName" in io.k8s.api.networking.v1.IngressBackend, ValidationError(Ingress.spec.rules[0].http.paths[0].backend): unknown field "servicePort" in io.k8s.api.networking.v1.IngressBackend];`

Comment: Trying to access by `scp.com:30080` is now working though, thanks to Your help.
Now, at least in theory, only the `ingress-srv.yaml` is left to be fixed. - Would be grateful for a bit more of Your time on that.

Comment: Hmm, seems you are using the new ingress specs. From what I read, those look correct. Did you install an ingress controller like nginx, because I don't see an nginx service in your serivices.

Comment: Yes, nginx was installed using ` kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/controller-v1.1.0/deploy/static/provider/cloud/deploy.yaml`