# Blazor Server App deployed to Azure Kubernetes hangs if I use @inject on razor components

Tags: asp.net, docker, blazor, blazor-server-side, azure-aks

I am developing an Asp.Net Blazor app that I deploy to Azure AKS. I have a razor component as a page started from NavMenu razor page:

```
    <AuthorizeView>
        <div class="nav-item px-3">
            <NavLink class="nav-link" href="clientdata">
                <span class="oi oi-list-rich" aria-hidden="true"></span> Clients
            </NavLink>
        </div>
    </AuthorizeView>
```

And I have a razor component page with some @inject(s):

```
@page "/clientdata"
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
@using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
@inject IExactConnectDbRepository DbRepository  
@inject AuthenticationStateProvider AuthProvider
@inject UserManager<UserData> UserManager

<h3>Client Data</h3>
```

If I run this locally everything works great and the page opens fine. If I deploy it to Azure Kubernetes in a Linux Docker container, Self-Contained and Framework-Dependent, the page with the injects does not open unless I press refresh which loads the page but if I add some content to the page, like a button, they don't respond to input while locally they work great. Note that cshtml files work fine with dependency injection. If I remove the injects then the page opens fine on AKS. Also there are no logs at the time that you open the page, only after refreshing I get logs.
What could be the problem and how to debug this?

Comment: When you don't use the Injected stuff then just leave it out.  If you do use it then this question is very incomplete.

Comment: Hi @HH I do use them but that's not the point. The point is that I can not inject anything and showing what I do in the code behind won't add anything to the question.

Comment: I guess your DbRepository is not responding. The problem is not the injecting mechanizmus but what the services are trying to do

Comment: Check if this helps- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70115934/problem-with-deploying-blazor-server-app-to-kubernetes

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/host-and-deploy/server?view=aspnetcore-8.0