# NodePort type service not accessible outside cluster

Tags: kubernetes, minikube, docker-for-windows

I am trying to setup a local cluster using minikube in a Windows machine. Following some tutorials in `kubernetes.io`, I got the following manifest for the cluster:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: external-nginx-deployment
  labels:
   app: external-nginx
spec: 
  selector: 
    matchLabels: 
      app: external-nginx
  replicas: 2 
  template: 
    metadata: 
      labels:
        app: external-nginx
    spec: 
      containers: 
      - name: external-nginx
        image: nginx 
        ports: 
        - containerPort: 80 
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service 
metadata: 
  name: expose-nginx 
  labels: 
   service: expose-nginx
spec: 
  type: NodePort 
  selector: 
    app: external-nginx 
  ports: 
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 80
    targetPort: 80
    nodePort: 32000
```

If I got things right, this should create a pod with a nginx instance and expose it to the host machine at port 32000.
However, when I run `curl http://$(minikube ip):32000`, I get a **connection refused** error.

I ran bash inside the service *expose-nginx* via `kubectl exec svc/expose-nginx -it bash` and from there I was able to access the *external-nginx* pods normally, which lead me to believe it is not a problem within the cluster.

I also tried to change the type of the service to LoadBalancer and enable the `minikube tunnel`, but got the same result.

Is there something I am missing?

Comment: please check if firewall is enabled ?

Comment: Do you mean the service's firewall? It seems I don't have permission to check the rules via `iptables` even though I'm logged as root. Is there an alternative way to do it?

Comment: i mean the firewall on the node / machine where this pod is running... ```systemctl status firewalld```

Comment: I just checked and the node firewall is disabled.

Comment: Which `minikube driver` is used? If docker then minikube VM is a big docker container within which other kubernetes components are run. And it's exposed inside. [`minikube service`](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/commands/service/) should work. Also you may consider using kubernetes feature within docker desktop which is much more convenient in my understanding. You will need to use `loadbalancer` then. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69113528/15537201).

Comment: Try executing `minikube service expose-nginx`

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I managed to get it working with `kubectl port-forward`. It worked fine for local development. After moving the cluster to a cloud provider, I changed the service type to `LoadBalancer` as it is the recommended type for this scenario and it worked right off the bat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost always by default `minikube` uses `docker` driver for the `minikube` VM creation. In the host system it looks like a big docker container for the VM in which other kubernetes components are run as containers as well. Based on tests `NodePort` for services often doesn't work as it's supposed to like accessing the service exposed via `NodePort` should work on `minikube_IP:NodePort` address.

Solutions are:

- for local testing use [`kubectl port-forward`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/port-forward-access-application-cluster/) to expose service to the local machine (which OP did)
- use [`minikube service`](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/commands/service/) command which will expose the service to the host machine. Works in a very similar way as `kubectl port-forward`.
- instead of `docker` driver use proper virtual machine which will get its own IP address (`VirtualBox` or `hyperv` drivers - depends on the system). [Reference](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/drivers/).
- (Not related to `minikube`) Use built-in feature `kubernetes` in Docker Desktop for Windows. I've already [tested it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69113528/15537201) and service type should be `LoadBalancer` - it will be exposed to the host machine on `localhost`.